# How to find text in images with the browser control+F

Tags: html, image, find, title

Have HTML pages with many sections and each section has a section title displayed as an image (to use nice font). The problem is that even if I specify an 'alt' and 'title' text on each image/title the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> browser functionality does not find the text. Thought two possible solutions but not very happy about them

1. Use embed fonts. 
   Problem: Can not find the font required by client to use and not sure about copyrights.
2. Have the text in the image in DIV near the image but hidden from user view.
   Problem: Can search engines consider this keyword stuffing? Will browser find text if display:none

Does anybody has a better solution?
Thanks
Riga

Comment: To answer Q2. No the CTRL-F will not work for text inside divs hidden with `display: none`.

Comment: Browsers cannot search text in images. `display:none` won't solve your problem too. I suggest using images only where is a need for them. Titles should definitely be written with plain text.

Comment: To answer Q2 too, you can hide text from user view without using    display:none; . Juste have to add    margin-left: -9999;

Comment: This would currently only be possible with a browser extension employing neural nets to recognize text in images. It's very possible but it might not run very quickly depending how many images were on the page. Highlighting the text is also possible, but again performance is uncertain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally the best approach to image replacement is to do so exclusively within the stylesheet.

The HTML should still look like:

```
<h2 id="fantastic-section-of-awesomeness"><span>This is an Ordinary Heading</span></h2>
```

Your CSS can then do:

```
h2#fantastic-section-of-awesomeness {
    background: ...; /* The replacement image */
}
h2 span {
    text-indent: -100000px;
}
```

Note that the text is not actually hidden. Some screen readers interpret `display: none;` incorrectly (even when given in a `media="screen"` stylesheet). Instead, we simply shift it far off the left side of the screen where it can't realistically be seen.

I have not specifically tested this for <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>, but the fact that the text is still technically visible should allow the browser to find it.

It will **not** be able to highlight the image as a match, however, which may still lead to confusion. There's no real way around that without using an `@font-face`.

Answer (score 5):

Why not try out the [Google Font Directory](http://code.google.com/webfonts)

> The Google Font Directory lets you
>   browse all the fonts available via the
>   Google Font API. All fonts in the
>   directory are available for use on
>   your website under an open source
>   license and are served by Google
>   servers.

Comment: The font required by my client is not in the set provided by Google. 
My client is not sure about the copyright
Tried with FFox 3.6 and all the fonts look the same.

Answer (score 2):

To accomplish this I have used the [typeface.js Javascript library](http://typeface.neocracy.org/download.html)

You can generate custom fonts for this library using this [generator](http://typeface.neocracy.org/fonts.html)

These sites also have examples and usage instructions.

Comment: Tried Ctrl+F and did not find the text

Comment: I'm looking at some of their examples and they aren't searchable. but I am using this on a website where searching works fine. I'll see if there is a specific flag for it.

Comment: what version of the typeface library are you using?

Comment: I did something wrong, Ctrl+F works on typeface website so yes text is searchable!

Answer (score 1):

You could also use the z-index on elements:

```
<html>
    <body>
        ...
        <div>
            <div style="position:absolute; z-index: 1">My Section Header</div>
            <div style="position:absolute; z-index: 2"><img src="test.png"/></div>
        </div>
        ...
    </body>
</html>
```

The image is in front of the text so that the user sees only the image but can find the section when he searches for "My Section Header".

Answer (score 0):

Hmm... I was going to recommend [Cufon](http://cufon.shoqolate.com/generate/) as an alternative to using generated images, but it's not perfect: Searching works in Firefox but not too well (bad positioning and no highlighting).

Still way better than images as headlines.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like times have changed, I came here looking for the API to style the search results lol [image]